# MSSQL How Can I Get the latest Amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the Latest amount, I already had some queries but instead it shows two records ,Im expecting to show only the the '7370' current amount

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a where lasttime in (select max(lasttime) from tablename b where a.id=b.id)
```

OR you can use row_number()

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by id order by lasttime desc) as rn from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: thanks, it show the latest date but I am specifying a unique ID on it which is '2019-85C-768'

Comment: have you executed this query - it will give your desired result @MavesNewbieHere

Comment: Oh.. thanks.. I got it now :) I Really Appreciate it..  I modified a bit here  
                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                
 select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) as rn from [kiddieCareDb].DBO.tbl_billing where ID = '2019-85C-768'
)A where rn=1

Answer (score 0):

Just add Top 1 before your fields.

```
Select TOP 1 fields from table
```

Comment: You need to mention order by also, TOP 1 without order by will not give the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT TOP 1 currentBalance FROM DBO.tbl_billing ORDER BY [date]
```